# Is there a way to define cell values dynamically in InAppSettingsKit?

Tags: ios, inappsettings

Seems everything is wired to get its info from the Settings.bundle values, for natural reasons.

But look at the "application information" in the example epp, it has its version hardcoded to "1.0". In the settings screen i use now (homemade) i fetch it dynamically and show it. Isn't there some way to override what is displayed there.

Would be great with a "dynamic value for cell specifier" or something you could override, so that i could write a method that fetches from the main bundle's CFBundleShortVersionString for that cell. I have other use cases where i want dynamic multi-select values i get and write to and from our server, not sure if i will be able to make it work with this api.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right - here's how I added Auto-App Version to InAppSettingsKit View.

In Root.inApp.plist (or in Root.plist) in Settings.bundle set Type of Version field to IASKCustomViewSpecifier:

```
<dict>
    <key>DefaultValue</key>
    <string>1.5</string>
    <key>Key</key>
    <string>version</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>VERSION</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>IASKCustomViewSpecifier</string>
</dict>
```

Next set some delegate for you `IASKAppSettingsViewController` for ex. at allocation point:

```
- (IASKAppSettingsViewController*)appSettingsViewController {
    if (!appSettingsViewController) {
        appSettingsViewController = [[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] init];
        appSettingsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    return appSettingsViewController;
}
```

Now you are able to use these delegate methods (they are called only for `IASKCustomViewSpecifier` fields):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier;
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier;
```

Here's my implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier {
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld-%d", specifier.type, (long)specifier.textAlignment, !!specifier.subtitle.length];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    if ([specifier.key isEqualToString:@"version"]) {
        [cell.textLabel setText:specifier.title];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"], [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Cell key: %@", specifier.key);
    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier {
    return 44.0f;
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: IASKAppSettingsViewController]